# Please help with this error when using separate class file in Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to use a function contained in a separate class file.

My separate class file is called EncounterGenerator.java.  And I call it like this:

`EncounterGenerator Encounter;`
`testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();`

So below is my main file called HelloAndroid.java:

```
package mot.HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
TextView tvIntro;
TextView tvNavigator;
TextView tvAction;
EncounterGenerator Encounter ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    //setup text views
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

     tvIntro = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvIntro);
     tvNavigator = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNavigator);
     tvAction = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAction);


    //display game intro
    tvIntro.setText("Text Adventure");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tvIntro.setText("This is a really cool text adventure game!");

    //define navigation buttons
    Button btnNorth = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNorth);

    btnNorth.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvIntro.setText("You go north");
            String testString = "nothing";
            try {
                testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            testString = Encounter.EncounterGeneratorText();
            tvIntro.setText(testString);

        }
    });
  }
}
```

and this is my separate class file called EncounterGenerator.java:

```
package mot.HelloAndroid;

public class EncounterGenerator {

public String EncounterGeneratorText() {
    String encounterText = "test value";  
    return encounterText;
}
}
```

Everytime I run it, and then click the button that calls the function EncounterGeneratorText() I get this error in my AVP:

The application Hello Android has stopped unexpectedly...please try again

If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The answer by @MByD is correct. In general, when you have errors, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error. In this case, you would have a `NullPointerException`, and it would indicate the line number where the exception occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate `Encounter`:

```
EncounterGenerator Encounter = new EncounterGenerator();
```

As a side note, variables in Java usually starts with a lower case letter.

Comment: Also, the `Thread.sleep(5000)` may just be enough to trigger an ANR since it's in `onCreate()`

Comment: @RivieraKid - That's true, I haven't even noticed that.

Comment: @MByD - wow thanks...so simple I can't believe I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

your method is not a static method. you need to instanciate your class in order to be able to call the method `EncounterGeneratorText()` .

Second point : try to use a `CountDownTimer(long delay, long unit);` not

```
Thread.sleep(long milliseconds);
```

**Note :**  methods always start with lowerCase  :) .